# Unable to send email local configuration problem

Tags: users, emails

I'm getting strange email errors on User Registration, when a user creates an account on my website, it emails them a link to activate their account, however, its started showing errors at the top of the email as shown below. I had everything working fine, emails going out, now i get these errors and Im not sure what I have changed to cause this. I did install the Honeypot module and Captua module last night (also have User Registration Password), but Im sure I tested afterwards and it was working fine. Any ideas? I have changed the email addresses below to make them anonymous.

On 8 Feb 2016, at 13:23, Mail Delivery System  wrote:

A message that you sent was rejected by the local scanning code that checks incoming messages on this system. The following error was given:

local configuration problem

------ This is a copy of your message, including all the headers. ------

Received: from 707134 by linweb.ahost.me with local (Exim 4.80.1)
   (envelope-from )
   id 1aSlmr-0003aW-L4
   for yyy@gmail.com; Mon, 08 Feb 2016 13:23:29 +0000
To: yyy@gmail.com
Subject: Account details for testuser at zzz Club
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
X-Mailer: Drupal
Sender: xxx@icloud.com
From: xxx@icloud.com
Message-Id: 
Date: Mon, 08 Feb 2016 13:23:29 +0000

testuser,

Thank you for registering at zzz Club. You may now log in and
verify your account by …..
[image]

Comment: There might be something wrong with your mail server. What mail type are you using?

Comment: no idea. I'm using 123reg hosting.

Comment: Have you installed a mail module or changes some parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by setting up a 'anything@mydomain.co.uk' with my host, and setting this to my email address under Configuration/Site Information, and also under the settings for the Trigger rule I set to send an email when a user is created.